# how do I instantiate something with only the y axis rotation matching the instanciators y rotation

Tags: c#, rotation

i'm making a swimming mechanic for my game and i need to instantiate the swim camera under neath the fps player when it hist the water. no mater what I try the swim cam wont have the same y rotation as the fps when its instantiated, and vice versa. what am i doing wrong? here is the script`Instantiate(swim, new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y -2, transform.position.z), rotation: transform.rotation=Quaternion.AngleAxis(0,0,0));`

Comment: It could be because `transform.rotation=Quaternion.AngleAxis(0,0,0)` will assign a value to `transform.rotation`

Comment: i ment to add  `transform.rotation=Quaternion.AngleAxis(0,tTransform.rotation.y,0);`sorry. it keeps throwing an error

Comment: Why do you sometimes use `transform` and sometimes `tTransform`?

Comment: ah, just a mispelling, im a little jittery is all